# run df.apply with lambda function in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, attributeerror

This code snippet works well:

```
df['art_kennz'] = df.apply(lambda x:myFunction(x.art_kennz), axis=1)
```

However, here I have hard coded the column name `art_kennz` on both places: `df['art_kennz']` and `x.art_kennz`. Now, I want to modify the script such that I have a list of column names and the df.apply runs for all those columns. So I tried this:

```
cols_with_spaces = ['art_kennz', 'fk_wg_sch']
for col_name in cols_with_spaces:
    df[col_name] = df.apply(lambda x: myFunction(x.col_name)
                                               , axis=1)
```

but this gives an error that:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'col_name'
```

because of `x.col_name`. Here, col_name is supposed to be the element from the for loop. What would be the correct syntax for this?

Comment: If myFunction can work with series you can use: df[list_of_cols] = df[list_of_cols].apply(lambda x: myFunction(x), axis=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
for col_name in cols_with_spaces:
    df[col_name] = df.apply(lambda x: myFunction(x[col_name])
```

Explanation: You can access the Serie using attribute syntax e.g `x.art_kennz`, but since `col_name` is a variable containing a string that represent the attribute, bracket syntax is the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

In this case `x.art_kennz` you use string but in `for-loop` you have variables you can not use `.variables`.

try this: *(In this approach you iterate row by row)*

```
for col_name in cols_with_spaces:
    df[col_name] = df.apply(lambda row: myFunction(row[col_name]), axis=1)
```

If you want to iterate columns by columns you can try this:

```
for col_name in cols_with_spaces:
    df[col_name] = df[col_name].apply(myFunction)
```